# Can't get Angularjs promises working right

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I know there's something I'm still missing when grasping promises.   I created this jsfiddle to highlight my issue.  I'm trying to count down and then go BOOM!   Yet the boom is coming first and then the countdown. What am I doing wrong/missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/urAZ7/1/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="Controller">
    <pre>{{output}}</pre>
</div>
```

JS

```
function Controller($scope, $q) {
    $scope.output = "Boom Goes the Dynamite in... "
    $scope.countdown = 10;

    var defer = $q.defer();

    defer.promise
        .then(function() {
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                $scope.output+="\n " + $scope.countdown;
                $scope.$apply();
                if ($scope.countdown === 0) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
                $scope.countdown--;    
            },1000);

            return true
        })
        .then(function(data) {    
            $scope.output+="\n " + "BOOM!!!!!";
        });

    defer.resolve();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should resolve promise only when your asynchronous operation is done. So you need to move `resolve` into `setInterval`:

```
function Controller($scope, $q) {
    $scope.output = "Boom Goes the Dynamite in... "
    $scope.countdown = 10;

    var defer = $q.defer();

    defer.promise.then(function() {
        $scope.output += "\n " + "BOOM!!!!!";
    });

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        $scope.output += "\n " + $scope.countdown;
        $scope.$apply();
        if ($scope.countdown === 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            defer.resolve(); // <--- resolve here
        }
        $scope.countdown--;
    }, 1000);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/urAZ7/4/

Comment: Thanks that helped.  However, I still am missing something in the understanding.  What if I had another timer than I wanted to chain in there?  How would the code look.  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/urAZ7/6/    Where I want timer1 to resolve then timer2 then Boom!